# Automotive connector ID

Tags: connector, identification

I have a 1998 Dodge Durango and am swapping transfer cases. The new case (NP242) uses a 4-pin switch (see photo). Dodge discontinued the adapter harness some time back and I have not been able to find a used one. The other end of the harness uses a Yakazi 090II Sealed Series that I have been able to find. My old switch used a Weather Pack connector here, so Dodge was all over the map on these. I know some Jeeps used this switch as well (99-01 Grand Cherokee?).

The terminals appear to be metri-pack 150, but the pin layout (cross vs square) and the notch (lower left in opening) does not align with any MP150 connector I have found. I did see one that looked similar for a 1992-97 LT1 oil pressure sensor, but tried one I had on an LT1 car of mine and it would not plug in.

The dimensions I measured were as follows:
Inner part where pins are: 15.5mm W x 12.5mm H
Outer part where seal sits: 22.0mm W x 17.4mm H

Thanks for any advice or help.

[image: New Process 242 transfer case switch top view]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found Aptiv/Delphi #12065298, which is the same size connector as used on my LT1. Since it's at the back of the engine, it's hard to see (I was trying the switch by feel), but apparently GM used a 1-pin connector here with the other 3 closed. According to the datasheet I looked at, the pin measurements are the same, so the 4-pin version of this should work. The part arrived today and I confirmed it is correct.